# CrashReport from Hockey, awkward Stacktrace with NSPlaceholderDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, crash, interface-builder

got some strange stack trace from an app i developed. here the stack trace:

```
Exception Type:  SIGTRAP
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x312b1848
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: 
attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35c48848 __kill + 8
1   CoreFoundation                      0x34dba957 __handleUncaughtException + 75
2   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x361e1345 _objc_terminate + 129
3   libc++abi.dylib                     0x000043c5 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 77
4   libc++abi.dylib                     0x00004451 operator delete(void*) + 1
5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x00005825 __cxa_current_exception_type + 1
6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x361e12a9 objc_exception_rethrow + 13
7   CoreFoundation                      0x34d1050d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 405
8   CoreFoundation                      0x34d1036d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
9   GraphicsServices                    0x36f85439 GSEventRunModal + 137
10  UIKit                               0x32df5cd5 UIApplicationMain + 1081
11  myApp                               0x000073f9 main (main.m:42)
```

this happens when you click on a tableview and a view should be pushed on the navigation controller. i never get this bug reproduced, so i could not say precisely, when it happened.

it could be that only iOS 5.1.1 is affected (only crash reports from this version exists).
i always check objects before adding them to a dict, so could loading xibs be a reason for that? perhaps it is kind of damaged, i recognized that sometimes xibs are in a very strange way...

thanks for every help

Comment: It seems you are using an older version of the SDK, since you don't have the `Last Exception Backtrace` available in the crash report. That would give you more details on where the crash happens. Make sure to check that you don't have an older PLCrashReporter version installed or any other lib that is catching exceptions. Contact us via support if you need help.

Comment: Usually crashes with `_NSPlaceholder...` are related to a memory leak as far as I remember. Maybe use the app for a longer time attached to Instruments and watch out for any leaks.

Comment: add a breakpoint handler for all exceptions and then debug from there

Answer (score 3):

If your crash reporter isn't reporting the exception backtrace, it needs to be fixed. Exceptions on the main thread have been caught and "re-thrown" (hence `objc_exception_rethrow`) since iOS 5 (nearly a year ago!).

I think __NSPlaceholderDictionary is just what you get by calling [NSDictionary alloc]. I suspect the culprit is code that does `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:x forKey:@"foo"]` without checking that `x` is non-nil.

iTunes Connect's crash reporting may also be helpful, though they display a *very* small subset of actual crashes.